# StyleBundle not rendering all the files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently learning responsive design, and following a [tutorial](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/zurb-foundation-4-with-asp-net-mvc-5)

The issue I have is the tutorial requests I download the latest Zurb Foundataion library, copy the files to the CSS folder and reference the CSS via the BundleConfig.cs file.

I have done this. I can see 3 files in my css (as per the tutorial, foundation.css, foundation.min.css and normalize.css).

However, it appears I don't need the first (since I have the .min version) and the code they request I use is

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Foundation/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/css/foundation.min.css",
                    "~/Content/css/normalize.css"));
```

I reference this code from my _Layout file

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Foundation/css")
```

The problem I have is, the web page doesn't render as desired. Viewing the source code show me the issue

The source code only shows

```
<link href="/Content/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

It is not rendering the foundation.min.css

So, just as a test, I removed the 
    `@Styles.Render("~/Content/Foundation/css")` from my _Layout file and coded the following 2 lines

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/foundation.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/normalize.css"/>
```

The page now renders as desired. I'm lost though as to why it didn't work when I added it as a bundle...

This is the BundleConfig.cs

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
            //            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));


            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Foundation/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/css/foundation.min.css",
                        "~/Content/css/normalize.css"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/foundation").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/foundation/foundation.js",
                        "~/Scripts/foundation/foundation.*"));
        }
    }
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this in your bundleconfig:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Foundation/css").Include(
                "~/Content/css/foundation.css",
                "~/Content/css/normalize.css"));
```

ASP.NET will automatically see that there's a .min-file and when you're not in debug-mode it will take the .min-file, otherwise it takes the normal one